# How do I scanf a row of n integers?

Tags: c

In c, I can use `scanf` to read say 3 integers separated by spaces from standard input like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
}
```

What if I don't know how many integers are in the row before hand? Say the user provides the number of integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int howManyIntegersToRead;
    scanf("%d", &howManyIntegersToRead);
    // Read in the integers with scanf( ... );
}
```

I'll need to malloc an array of size `sizeof(int) * howManyIntegersToRead` bytes. How do I actually read the standard input data into the allocated memory? I can't construct a formatted string with `howManyIntegersToRead` %ds. Well, I could, but there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try like this using `for` loop:

```
int i, size;
int *p;
scanf("%d", &size);
p = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
for(i=0; i < size; i++)
    scanf("%d", &p[i]);
```

Comment: Does not account for multi-row input.

Comment: Yes it does, `%d` skips whitespace (including newlines)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int howManyIntegersToRead;
    scanf("%d", &howManyIntegersToRead);
    // Read in the integers with scanf( ... );
    // allocate memory
    int a[howManyIntegersToRead];  

     for(int i=0;i<howManyIntegersToRead;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
```

Comment: [Variables Length Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array): `int a[howManyIntegersToRead]`. Both in C++ and before C99, it's not standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic allocation and loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int count, i;
    int *ar;

    printf("Input count of integers: ");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    ar = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    if (ar == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int* integers, i = 0;
    do {

    integers = realloc(integers, sizeof(int) * (i + 1));
    if(integers == NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    printf("enter an integer: ");
    scanf(" %d", &integers[i]);
    printf("\nentered: %d\n", integers[i]);
} while(integers[i++] != 0);//here put your ending of choice


free(integers);
return 0;
}
```